# can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException) on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, buildpack

When I run heroku run bundle install it gives me an error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:308:in `bin_path': can't find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
from /app/bin/bundle:3:in `<main>'
```

and when I am `heroku run rails console` it gives an error

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /app/bin/spring:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:3:in `load'
from /app/bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

What I do?

I addd nodejs buildpack in it

Comment: Heroku has ruby and bundler preinstalled. When you push your repo to heroku, it sees that you have "Gemfile" and runs `bundle install` automatically. What happens when you push your repo to heroku? Can you add the output here as well?

Comment: I add nodejs buildlpack

Comment: When I run heroku run rake db:migrate alos getting same error

Comment: Are you building a Rails app or Node?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar experience recently

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:308:in `bin_path': can't find gem
>   bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

But solved by using both `Node` and `Ruby` buildpacks.

Check your current buildpacks

```
heroku buildpacks
```

Add `Ruby` buildpack after `Node`

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 2 https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby
```